# When running MPI is there a way to execute sequential code first and then run the parallel code

Tags: sockets, parallel-processing, pthreads, mpi

I am writing code and I need to initialize variables and execute a series of tasks sequentially and only once. Following that, I am currently using pthreading to run parallel processes before returning to sequential code to sort the data and perform a binary search. The parallel processes are simply a many reads from multiple (roughly 35) sockets simultaneously. I have been asked to implement the same setup using MPI, and my current understanding is if I use MPI every single process will execute the entire program and the parallal processing is not confined to the lines where MPI_Init_thread and MPI_Finalize are placed. I my understanding correct? Or is there a way to execute sequential code before and after parallel code while using MPI?

Comment: your understanding is correct. you can add a few lines of codes and perform some job only on rank 0 (keep in mind other MPI tasks are alive and likely spinning). An other approach would be to start 1 MPI task, and then `MPI_Comm_spawn()` when extra MPI tasks are needed for parallelism. Keep in mind `MPI_Comm_spawn()` semantic is not very intuitive, and that might not work best is you are running under a resource manager, so starting with all the MPI tasks is the simplest option.

Answer (score 3):

- MPI_Init is called prior to any calls to other MPI routines. Its
  purpose is to initialize the MPI environment.
- MPI_Finalize is called at the end of the computation, and it
  performs various clean-up tasks to terminate the MPI
  environment.
- MPI_Init also strips off any MPI related command-line arguments.

If you want to execute sequential code you can do

```
 if (myrank == 0){ 
 //code
 }
```

and the main thread (with id = 0) will execute the code alone so you ll have no parralelism in that spot.